# How to add an IPv6 address?

Tags: networking, network-interface, networkmanager, ipv6, ipv4

The official Debian networking documentation tells to use:

```
ifup 6to4
```

But ifup is not found (ifupdown and ifupdown2 are commands not found too, even after having been installed). Does it have something to do with prefix delegation? If so, do I have to configure it?

And the linux documentation project (i.e. tldp.org) says to use

```
ip -6 addr add <ipv6address>/<prefixlength> dev <interface>
```

but ONLY when you have a global IPv6 address, which is not my case. 
I read other tutorials which nevertheless did'nt enabled me to reach a solution, so I'm asking for help here.

I'm using Debian stable 10.4 with Xfce 4.12 and Zsh 5.7.1.

I have a TP-LINK N900 Wireless PCI Express Adapter TL-WDN4800 and a Intel I219-V Gibabit LAN controller.

As a side note, the Ethernet network dialog in the desktop panel prints: "device not managed".

MAIN OBJECTIVE: I need to activate IPv6 connectivity to fetch some IPv6 web servers.

```
➜ ping6 wiki.debian.org     
connect: Network is unreachable
```

Whereas echo requests with IPv4 work without any loss:

```
➜ ping4 wiki.debian.org
PING wilder.debian.org (82.195.75.112) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from wilder.debian.org (82.195.75.112): icmp_seq=1 ttl=52 time=35.4 ms
64 bytes from wilder.debian.org (82.195.75.112): icmp_seq=2 ttl=52 time=35.3 ms
64 bytes from wilder.debian.org (82.195.75.112): icmp_seq=3 ttl=52 time=190 ms
64 bytes from wilder.debian.org (82.195.75.112): icmp_seq=4 ttl=52 time=35.3 ms
64 bytes from wilder.debian.org (82.195.75.112): icmp_seq=5 ttl=52 time=181 ms
64 bytes from wilder.debian.org (82.195.75.112): icmp_seq=6 ttl=52 time=181 ms
^C
--- wilder.debian.org ping statistics ---
6 packets transmitted, 6 received, 0% packet loss, time 12ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 35.277/109.735/190.063/74.440 ms
```

Here are my network devices:

```
➜ ip addr show
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: enp0s31f6: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 4c:cc:6a:cf:5f:bd brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
3: wlp4s0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 18:d6:c7:1c:b7:d5 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.0.189/24 brd 192.168.0.255 scope global dynamic noprefixroute wlp4s0
       valid_lft 7171sec preferred_lft 7171sec
    inet6 fe80::b08:601b:a8d8:1474/64 scope link noprefixroute 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

You can notice in the before-last line that the LOCAL link address (i.e. fe80::) have a /64 mask, which is a GLOBAL one! A local link mask would be /10 where as a global address would start by 2xxx (e.g. 2001::).

Except for lo which probably means localhost, I do not know what are enp0s31f6 and wl4ps0.
I only know that enp0s31f6 was renamed from eth0 but that doesn't explain to me anything, apart from the fact I'm using new syntax for network interfaces names:

```
➜ sudo dmesg | grep -i eth
[    1.701805] e1000e 0000:00:1f.6 eth0: (PCI Express:2.5GT/s:Width x1) 4c:cc:6a:cf:5f:bd
[    1.701809] e1000e 0000:00:1f.6 eth0: Intel(R) PRO/1000 Network Connection
[    1.701912] e1000e 0000:00:1f.6 eth0: MAC: 12, PHY: 12, PBA No: FFFFFF-0FF
[    1.703934] e1000e 0000:00:1f.6 enp0s31f6: renamed from eth0
[    7.706185] Ethernet Channel Bonding Driver: v3.7.1 (April 27, 2011)
```

Here are some settings to help you understand my network configuration:

```
➜ cat /etc/network/interfaces
# This file describes the network interfaces available on your system
# and how to activate them. For more information, see interfaces(5).

source /etc/network/interfaces.d/*

# The loopback network interface
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

auto enp0s31f6
    allow-hotplug enp0s31f6
    iface enp0s31f6 inet dhcp
    iface enp0s31f6 inet6 auto
```

```
➜ cat /etc/hosts
127.0.0.1       localhost
127.0.1.1       omega.dominion  omega

# The following lines are desirable for IPv6 capable hosts
::1     localhost ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
fe00::0 ip6-localnet
ff00::0 ip6-mcastprefix
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters
ff02::3 ip6-allhosts
```

```
➜ cat /etc/resolv.conf
# Generated by NetworkManager
nameserver 192.168.0.1
```

Please can someone help me to correctly set up IPv6 connectivity?

**EDIT:**

I'm behind a TP-LINK AC1350 wireless router Archer C59 v1.0 (but no proxy configured) (general specs are here: https://www.tp-link.com/us/home-networking/wifi-router/archer-c59/#specifications)

I'm using nn-connection-editor application to manage my network. Here are my current settings:

```
➜ sudo cat /etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/TP-LINK_902C                

[connection]
id=TP-LINK_902C
uuid=f2fef445-f44e-4216-8d51-eb4dd4e23ea6
type=wifi
permissions=
timestamp=1589139366

[wifi]
mac-address-blacklist=
mode=infrastructure
seen-bssids=50:C7:BF:90:90:2C;
ssid=TP-LINK_902C

[wifi-security]
key-mgmt=wpa-psk
psk-flags=1

[ipv4]
dns=8.8.8.8;8.8.4.4;
dns-search=
method=auto

[ipv6]
addr-gen-mode=eui64
dns-search=
ip6-privacy=2
method=auto
```

Now I run the diagnostic tool ndisc6:

```
➜ rdisc6 wlp4s0
Soliciting ff02::2 (ff02::2) on wlp4s0...
Timed out.
Timed out.
Timed out.
No response.
```

Which is strange because of the LAN discovery on all routers via echo requests seems to work correctly:

```
➜ ping -c3 -I wlp4s0 ff02::02
ping6: Warning: source address might be selected on device other than wlp4s0.
PING ff02::02(ff02::2) from :: wlp4s0: 56 data bytes
64 bytes from fe80::52c7:bfff:fe90:902c%wlp4s0: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=45.4 ms
64 bytes from fe80::52c7:bfff:fe90:902c%wlp4s0: icmp_seq=2 ttl=64 time=1.65 ms
64 bytes from fe80::52c7:bfff:fe90:902c%wlp4s0: icmp_seq=3 ttl=64 time=1.62 ms

--- ff02::02 ping statistics ---
3 packets transmitted, 3 received, 0% packet loss, time 5ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 1.624/16.230/45.421/20.641 ms
```

I took some screenshots from web administration's interface (i.e. http://tplinkwifi.net) to help investigating further:

1) IPv6 internet settings

[image: IPv6 internet settings]

2) Possible options
[image: possible options for IPv6 settings]

3) IPv4 general settings
[image: IPv4 general settings]

4) Their counter-part in IPv6
[image: Their counter-part in IPv6]

5) Other wireless network system parameters
[image: System parameters]

**EDIT2:**
It seems my modem supplied by my ISP doesn't provide any IPV6 connectivity, so it become clear that I need a more recent modem or a IPv6 tunnel. I from now on consider the question answered and I thank you  user4556274, Johan Myréen and bey0nd for your insights :)

Comment: the link-local address space is `fe80::/10`, but the link-local address on an end node will be `/64`.  The `/64` netmask itself tells you nothing about whether an address is link-local, universal-local, or global.

Comment: You will either need to your ISP to provide IPv6 connectivity, or you need to set up a IPv6 tunnel via tunnel broker.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe some basics first:

A IPv6 address of a host/interface always consists of 128bit which include the prefix (first 64bit) and the interface identification [IID] (last 64bit). Therefor the CIDR notation for a host/interface address is always /64.

The scope of an IPv6 host/interface address is one of the following:

**Local-Link**: An address out of the fe80::/64 range. As the prefix is always *fe80:0:0:0*, there is no distinct separation of layer 3 networks and therefore this address is only used for communication in the current layer 2 segment of the connected LAN.
**Local**     : An address out of the fd00::/8 range which consists of a 64bit prefix and a 64bit IID. It should only be routed in the LAN and not over the internet.
**Global**    : An address out of the 2000::/3 range which can be routed over the internet and also consists of a 64bit prefix and a 64bit IID.

Your computer seems to have two network interfaces.
- *enp0s31f6* which seems to be a Ethernet interface without connection and
- *wlp4s0* which seems to be a wireless network interface connected to an AP.

As there is only a Link-Local address on the wireless interface, it seems that this interface is either
- not configured to accept any automated configuration (SLAAC or DHCPv6) or
- the access point (AP) doesn't provide an IPv6 network.

edit: As the result of `rdisc6 wlp4s0` shows, there is no IPv6 autoconfig information broadcasted in your network, even so the router seems to be set to *SLAAC + Stateless DHCP*. Therefore, as Johan Myréen stated in his comment, you'll need to talk to your ISP to see if there is IPv6 available at all or find a way to tunnel IPv6 with a Tunnel provider.